# Generate Pdf from user input

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I need to take multiple inputs from user, print user provided data in table format, create pdf which contains that table and that table would be repeated number of times provided by user. I'm not sure whether it can be achieved by vba macros or can be done through code in c#.

Input:
Name: ABC
School: XYZ
Number of Tags you want to print: 12

Expected output:
A pdf file containing 12 tables and each table has two rows i.e, Name and School.

Answer (score 0):

This is very open ended but if I understand what you want, there are some ways to go about this. You can record a macro in Microsoft Excel to save a spreadsheet as a pdf, and call that macro with in vba code. It should also be possible to read in user inputs, or require that a user fill out field entries. Depending on your experience/what you are looking for you may also want to look into using Python. There are python libraries for reading/writing spreadsheet data and for making PDF's (report lab). If you prompt the user to enter information then you could skip spreadsheets entirely. In my mind there are a lot of ways to approach this problem and you should think about who will be using this to decide what the best way to go about this would be.